# Allow sudo but no local login with pam access

Tags: sudo, pam, access-control

Assume we have two servers **A** and **B**

> **A**: Heavily locked down. Requires TOTP (google authenticator), password and valid public key. This server allows users to log into B
> with their adm accounts (username-adm). These accounts have passwordless sudo on the remote  machines.
>
> **B**: Can be logged into from multiple places, only requires password and valid user.

Now, we want to *disable* local login for our adm accounts. Meaning they **cannot** log into server B as *user* and then switch to *user-adm*.

I thought I could accomplish this as follows (we are using PAM and LDAP).

**/etc/sudoers.d**

```
+it-org-adm-group ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**/etc/security/access.d**

```
+:@it-org-adm-group : SERVER-A-IPV4 SERVER-A-IPV6
```

**The problem is that sudo evaluates the pam stack!** This means that sudo does not work for these users unless we explicitly allow local login

**/etc/security/access.d**

```
+:@it-org-adm-group : SERVER-A-IPV4 SERVER-A-IPV6 LOCAL
```

So is there any way to block a *particular group* from *local* login, but allow sudo? Other users should be free to switch users or whatnot (given they have the correct credidentials). Note we have to use PAM as it is deeply integrated into our suite of servers.